# Install OpenCL library from device

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, opencl

I need to get the `libOpenCL.so` file to develop OpenCL apps.
I am not able to locate the file.

- Host system: Ubuntu 12.04
- Device: Moto G (It has support for OpenCL and I have tested it).

Comment: Well, you need to install an OpenCL library...

Comment: Where on the device have you looked? On the devices I target, it's usually in `/system/vendor/lib/libOpenCL.so`.

Comment: thks both of u.@jprice in the target device (moto g) i am not able to find the /system directory.i m getting only /sys. Any clues?

Comment: @user3806428 You could run `adb shell 'find / -name libOpenCL.so 2>/dev/null'`

Comment: thks jprice but there is no response from termonal\ when i run above command